# PHP inclusione locally

Tags: php, inclusion

I have the same menu for all the pages of my website. I want include it in all the page with a .php file
I created with MAMP PRO a fake domani to try it locally on mu MAC.

I created my index.html and the other pages:

```
<html>
 <header>
    <title>Inclusion test</title>
</header>  

<body>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="pippo.html">Pippo</a></li>
        <li><a href="pluto.html">Pluto</a></li>
    </ul> 

    <h1>Welcome on Disneyland!</h1>


</body> 

</html>
```

I created this php file:

```
   <?php
   echo "<a href="index.html">Home</a>";
   "<a href="pippo.html">Pippo</a>";
   "<a href="pluto.html">Pluto</a>";
   ?>
```

After I included it on my index.html with this line rule:

```
<?php include 'menu.php';?>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change extension of your `index.html` to `index.php`. An HTML file doesn't know how to execute PHP codes.

`<?PHP include('menu.php'); ?>` is a PHP statement but to HTML file, it's just a sentence(text)

Comment: Thanks but I didn't resolve. I changed all the prefix from html to php but it doesn't work! Are you sure is correct my php code?